# plot_decision_regions TypeError: axis() got an unexpected keyword argument 'y_min'

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
plot_decision_regions(X_train, y_train, clf = model)
____________________________________________________
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-82-178b28808997> in <cell line: 15>()
     13 ax.contour(XX, YY, Z, colors = 'k', levels = [-1, 0, 1], linestyles=["--", "-", "--"])
     14 
---> 15 plot_decision_regions(X_train, y_train, clf = model);

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py in axis(self, arg, emit, **kwargs)
   2125             self.set_ylim(ymin, ymax, emit=emit, auto=yauto)
   2126         if kwargs:
-> 2127             raise _api.kwarg_error("axis", kwargs)
   2128         return (*self.get_xlim(), *self.get_ylim())
   2129 

TypeError: axis() got an unexpected keyword argument 'y_min'
```

How to solve this error?

I did try all other arguments but was not able to solve this error as I don't see the argument called 'y_min' defined for this module.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is related to the mlxtend library. Most likely, you use an old version. You have to update it, e.g. run something like (if you use pip):

```
pip install mlxtend --upgrade --no-deps
```

Warning! I would record mlextend's version first, since upgrading one library, might require updating others (and could break some libs). If you know the version you can always undo the upgrade, i.e., install the prior version using the exact version number.

In my case, I was using Google Colab, which for some reason also uses an old version by default. To upgrade run before the import of mlextend

```
!pip install mlxtend --upgrade --no-deps
```